# How to use Vue Plugins Correctly? <PluginName> is not defined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, es6-modules

Im learning to make Vue Plugin, based on https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html,
this is my simple code:

plugin1.js:

```
AlertPlugin.install = function (Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$classicalert = function (message) {
        alert(message)
    };
};
```

app.js:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
import AlertPlugin from './plugin1.js'
Vue.use(AlertPlugin);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(Main)
});
```

when im trying to run it, the web page become blank, and error **AlertPlugin is not defined**.

please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `plugin1.js` file, you are attempting to set the `install` property of the `AlertPlugin` object, which (as the error says) is not defined.

Your `plugin1.js` file should look like this:

```
export default {
  install: function (Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$classicalert = function (message) {
      alert(message)
    };
  }
}
```

This defines a `default` object to export containing a property `install`. When you import this object as `AlertPlugin`, like you are doing in `app.js`, it will result in an `AlertPlugin` object with the `install` property you defined in the plugin's file.